# Designing Game Randomization Logic

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game that adds sprites to my scene randomly. The randomness is weighted and I can change the weight based on the supplied parameters to my method to change which sprite I want to be added more than others.

Now the game is round based. So, during round one I would like for the weight of the sprite the user needs to be shown a lot which I will set by the weight, and set the other sprites at a lower weight to make it easy in the first stage.

The second round I would like to change the weights up and make them a little harder by mixing more of the unneeded sprites into the scene.

The problem is I don't want to hard code this since I want the user to go on as many rounds as they can. So how could I make this where it isn't hard coded to do what I needed it to do?

Hope this makes sense

**EDIT:**

So basical what happens is i have a wiehgt method that controls the probability of a sprite being added to the scene over the other 3 sprites.

```
updateWeights(int itemNumber, double weight);
```

That is my method i use to update each sprites weight by supplying the sprites itemNumber then the weight i want to use.

What i would like to do is as the user gets further along in the game based on a requirement i set the game will gradually get harder by changing the weights to different weights. The thing is the sprite that MUST show on the scene more than the others should always be higher than the others(this is why i don't want to use a random generator). See what i mean? If anyone sees easier logic to this please feel free to suggest it.

Comment: May be you could add some example to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out some function of round number to determine weights.

For instance, try `weight(n) = 1/(1 + e^(-n + b))`, where you can vary `b` for balance. This always returns a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Could you elabortate more on your answer?